# how to run two different queries in a single query using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, unions

I have a Invoice table with these columns.,

```
id total date         country
1   50   2016-01-25   USA
2   40   2016-01-24   UK
3   30   2016-01-22   France
4   40   2016-01-26   UK
5   50   2016-01-18   USA
6   60   2016-02-20   USA
7   70   2016-02-21   USA
8   55   2016-02-18   UK
9   75   2016-02-19   France
```

and I want to get USA total amount, NON USA total amount group by month, i am using these query i get only USA total amount

```
SELECT MONTH(date),YEAR(date),SUM(total) as usa_amount 
FROM Invoice 
WHERE YEAR(date) = '2016' 
  AND country='USA' 
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

and i am getting this result

```
MONTH(date)  YEAR(date)   usa_amount
01            2016         100
02            2016         130
```

I want to this result using mysql unions or anything?

```
MONTH(date)  YEAR(date)   usa_amount  non_usa_amount
01            2016         100        110
02            2016         130        130
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` in the `sum()`

```
SELECT MONTH(date),
       SUM(case when country =  'USA' then total else 0 end) as usa_amount,
       SUM(case when country <> 'USA' then total else 0 end) as non_usa_amount 
FROM Invoice 
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2016
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

Comment: I want to Non USA amount also with the same query?

Comment: how do we use second column with this same query usa_refunds, non_usa_refunds @juergen d

Comment: Try to figure it out and not not possible, ask another question.